# Swipe up transition in IONIC

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i want to implement page up transition in my very first page of app.
in my entire app i have used "state: for navigation and it is working fine as left and right transitions in pages. but what i want is transition towards upwards direction in my very first page. like, when when user swipes up there is a upwards transition and new page appears. 
i can't find any way to implement the same. 
currently i am using following code for navigation.

```
    .state('SignIn', {
      url: '/SignIn',
      templateUrl: 'templates/SignInView.html',
      controller: 'SignInViewCtrl'
    })


    $scope.navigate= function () {
    $state.go('SignIn');
    }
```

is there any way to apply transition in this navigation ? or is there any alternative for the same ?

Comment: Any update ? Did you able to achieve it ? I want the same thing

Comment: no brother, tried a lot but no results. 
just left it to default IONIC transitions.